# Literal character escapes in VimL string

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I'm trying to use vimlsp server to help me write VimL, but it is prevented for me due to a parse problem with a literal carriage return (`^M`) char inside this code:

```
function! ChompCtrlM(string)
    return substitute(a:string, '^M$', '', '')
endfunction
```

It turns out I'm not actually even using this, so I'm able to dodge the bullet, but is there a hex escape string literal syntax for VimL? Google yielded nothing.

Comment: It's the actual control character? I don't think Vim should barf on that. It's common to use these (entered with `ctrl-V` then `ctrl-M`). Or is it supposed to be three character regex? `^` then `M` then `$`??? ;)

Comment: Yeah, it's the literal control char. It's in my vimrc, ergo vim (neither nvim) barf on it, but vim-lsp certainly doesn't know what to do about it, and to the extent that it halts parsing and effectively bricks it.

Comment: It might just be ok if I were to write it as `"\r"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can normally use double quoted strings for this purpose. They accept a range of backslash escape sequences to produce special characters without having to input the special character literals into your buffer.

The character that shows as `^M` is the carriage return and you can enter it as `"\r"`. You can also use key names in double quoted backspace sequences. The key notation for carriage return is `<CR>`, so you can produce it in a string with `"\<CR>"`. Both `"\r"` and `"\<CR>"` are equivalent and produce the same string.

See [`:help expr-quote`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-quote) for a full list of backslash escape sequences that are recognized in a double quoted string.

In your specific case, you could rewrite your function as:

```
function! ChompCtrlM(string)
    return substitute(a:string, "\r$", '', '')
endfunction
```

This will hopefully avoid the conflict with vimlsp that you found with the special character literal.